# Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500

Tags: c, hyperledger-fabric

I have created a chaincode and I am trying to install it on the peer organization. I am able to package the chaincode on the peer organization but when it turns to install phase, I got error message:

```
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 2
# github.com/Nik-U/pbc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lpbc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Nik-U's go wrapper of the PBC library [Nik-U pbc](https://github.com/Nik-U/pbc). In his homepage, description shows:

> This package must be compiled using cgo. It also requires the installation of GMP and PBC. During the build process, this package will attempt to include <gmp.h> and <pbc/pbc.h>, and then dynamically link to GMP and PBC.

Here's what I have tried:

1. I have manually configured the GMP and PBC under the Nik-U's directory and changed all the addresses of <gmp.h> and <pbc.h> to the right location.
2. I have tried to use command `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpbc.so libpbc.so` and `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so` to create link library files, but it shows the same error message.
3. As the Nik-U wrapper uses cgo, I changed the sentence in c.go file from `#cgo LDFLAGS: -lpbc -lgmp` to `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lpbc -lgmp`. Inside the /usr/loca/lib there are: `libgmp.a  libgmp.la  libgmp.so  libgmp.so.10  libgmp.so.10.4.1  libpbc.a  libpbc.la  libpbc.so  libpbc.so.1  libpbc.so.1.0.0`. This change did not work. I still got the same error message.
4. I copied all files of the directory /usr/local/lib to the same directory of the docker container using command `docker cp **.so containerName:/usr/local/lib/`. It does not work.

Here are what I doubt that may be the problem:

1. I am using go.mod file to manage all dependencies but the go.mod does not manage the original PBC library and GMP library. However, I do not know how to use go module to manage these two libraries (written in C?).
2. Nik-U's pbc wrapper has to link PBC and GMP libraries dynamically, which is why my efforts to manually configure and install them in the subdirectory, and change the include information such as from `#include <pbc/pbc.h>` to `#include <pbc-0.5.14/include/pbc.h>` of no use.

Can anybody help..

Comment: What is this containerName? Is it a peer? `docker cp **.so containerName:/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: Yes. It's one of the peers of the organization.

Answer (score 0):

In hyperledger fabric, chaincode is executed in the form of sandbox based on virtual environment. In other words, it is not executed in the peer, but in a new docker container.
Even if you move the *.so file to the peer, it seems that a `cannot find` error has occurred because the newly created chaincode does not import it.

To solve this, two tasks are required.

#### 1. import library to `fabric-ccenv` docker image

The go chaincode container of the fabric occurs in the image of fabric-ccenv. Based on the fabric-ccenv image, create a new image with your library embedded

```
FROM fabric-ccenv:<your_fabric_tag>
COPY <your_src_library_path> <your_target_library_path>
```

```sh
docker build -f <your_dockerfile> -t fabric-ccenv:<your_new_fabric_tag>
```

#### 2. Change core.yaml of fabric-peer

You have to change the peer's configuration. That is, set the configuration for chaincode in core.yaml.
You can set information about fabric-ccenv in the builder item of chaincode. Change this value to the value of your image created in step 1 above.

```yaml
chaincode:
    id:
        path:
        name:
  #builder: $(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-ccenv:$(TWO_DIGIT_VERSION)
    builder: $(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-ccenv:<your_new_fabric_tag>
    pull: false
    golang:
        runtime: $(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-baseos:$(TWO_DIGIT_VERSION)
        dynamicLink: false
```

Comment: I followed your solution and still got error. Here's what I did: 1. I created a directory "dockerfile" and created `Dockerfile` in it. Commands inside Dockerfile are: `FROM hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib
COPY lib .`; 2. I copied all lib* files to dockerfile/lib and ran command `docker build -f Dockerfile -t fabric-ccenv:test`; 3. I changed my core.yaml file to `builder: fabric-ccenv:test`; 4. I used `docker-compose up -d` to start everything; 5. I tried to package and install the chaincode. Then I received same error messages. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: If so, can you try it in fabric-baseos, not ccenv? Sorry, but I may have confuse the image. The actual go language runs in baseos.

Comment: I just tried and build a new image called `fabric-baseos:test` and changed corresponding setting in the core.yaml file. It still does not work. This is what I got when I tried to check whether my lib files were properly copied: `$ docker run -t -i hyperledger/fabric-baseos:test sh
/usr/local/lib $ ls
libgmp.a          libgmp.la         libgmp.so         libgmp.so.10      libgmp.so.10.4.1  libpbc.a          libpbc.la         libpbc.so         libpbc.so.1       libpbc.so.1.0.0` Since the image was built correctly, I am wondering if the problem takes place elsewhere.

Comment: I followed the error message `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lpbc` and tried to find **x86_64-alpine-linux-musl** this directory. However, I only got x86_64-redhat-linux inside the gcc dir. I also searched the image and did not find this dir either.

Comment: It seems that the initial series of docker images should be alpine. The fabric was converted to alpine from version 2.x.

Comment: There can be several ways.
First, when creating the existing 1.4.x version of docker itself, build in alpine series (you need to analyze and modify the make docker command script in fabric github)

Comment: Or get x86_64-alpine-linux-musl from apline and insert it into your image. and so on ....

Comment: After all, the current problem and solution is one.
The problem is that you can't find the library referenced in your chaincode, and you need to insert all the related libraries into the chaincode docker so you can reference them.

Comment: I linked libgmp.* and libpbc.* to the local directory `../artifacts/src/../../pbc-0.5.14/` and changed the settings in `c.go`: `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./pbc-0.5.14 -lpbc -lgmp`. The errors shown above vanished...INSTEAD, I got two new errors: `warning: libm.so.6, needed by vendor/github.com/Nik-U/pbc/pbc-0.5.14/libpbc.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)` and warning: libc.so.6, needed by vendor/github.com/Nik-U/pbc/pbc-0.5.14/libpbc.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`. This time, linking libm.so.6 & libc.so.6 to the same dir does not help anymore..

Comment: Is it possible to check if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is properly set?

Comment: and check this link [cmd/cgo](https://golang.org/src/cmd/cgo/doc.go?h=sin)
`Also for security reasons, only a limited set of characters are
permitted, notably alphanumeric characters and a few symbols, such as
'.', that will not be interpreted in unexpected ways. Attempts to use
forbidden characters will get a "malformed #cgo argument" error.`

Comment: It is confirmed that your command contains a dot '.'