# Kubernetes Pod - External library dependency

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, alpine-linux

I'm using the [Vault's Kubernetes Helm Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/hashicorp/vault).

Before proceeding, I'd like to mention that my issue is extremely similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228778/error-chaincode-install-failed-with-status-500) one, but it didn't help.

So, inside Vault, I need to load a **custom** plugin, which has two dependencies: *libpbc* and *libgmp*.
While trying to install the plugin, I get this error:
`* fork/exec /vault/plugins/plugin_name: no such file or directory`
which is not normal, for the simple reason that everything seems okay (the `plugin_directory` (a Vault dependency) exists, the plugin is indeed under /vault/plugins etc).

So, by investigating, I found out that there is a big issue.
Executing `ldd /vault/plugins/*plugin_name*`, I get:

```
Error loading shared library libpbc.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by vault/plugins/plugin_name)
Error loading shared library libgmp.so.10: No such file or directory (needed by vault/plugins/plugin_name)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7eff0c4ba000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7eff0c4ba000)
Error relocating vault/plugins/plugin_name: pbc_param_init_a1_gen: symbol not found
Error relocating vault/plugins/plugin_name: pbc_param_init_e_gen: symbol not found
Error relocating vault/plugins/plugin_name: pbc_cm_search_d: symbol not found
...
```

What I have already tried:

1. Moving the libraries inside the pod and under `/usr/local/lib`. No. Error: `tar: can't create symlink 'libpbc.so' to 'libpbc.so.1.0.0': Permission denied`
2. Moving the libraries "anywhere" and exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Again, no. Not working (Expected)
3. Any other thing that came to my mind and got me a "Permission denied" error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

I created a custom Vault image and in the Dockerfile I made it to include all the dependencies

```
RUN apk add build-base gmp-dev ...
```

For the libpbc, I `wget` the files, decompress them and then

```
./configure
make
make install
```